# Python Turtle: why centered square for odd size is uneven/distorted?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Do you have any idea why following code produces distorted square when side of the square is odd?

```
from turtle import *
s = 67.0

pu();fd(s/2.0);rt(90.0);fd(s/2.0);pd()
for _ in range(4):
  rt(90.0)
  fd(s)
pu();fd(-s/2.0);rt(-90.0);fd(-s/2.0);pd()

done()
```

I got such [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxUL3.jpg)

Above code works well when side is even. Python 3.5.0 was used. I have the same effect under linux, windows native and cygwin.

PARTIAL SOLUTION (EDIT): I made discovery, when I add very small number to `s` everything works well... `s = 67.0 + 1e-10`. But have no idea why?

EDIT: here is a more complicated program where above solution doesn't work. Here again I start drawing figure in the middle of square. I tried other strategy, drawing from the corner and in this case `1e-10` solution works.

```
from turtle import *
from math import sqrt
from random import *

plg = 53 - 1e-10 # side size, even - works well, odd - not
sk = sqrt(2) / 2.0

speed(0)

def square(q):
  s = q / 2.0
  penup()
  forward(s)
  right(90)
  forward(s)
  pendown()
  begin_fill()
  for i in range(4):
    right(90)
    forward(q)
  end_fill()
  penup()
  forward(-s)
  right(-90)
  forward(-s)
  pendown()

def triangle(q,rot):
  begin_fill()
  right(45 + rot)
  forward(q * sk)
  right(-135)
  forward(q)
  right(-90)
  forward(q)
  right(-135)
  forward(q * sk)
  end_fill()
  setheading(0)

pu(); forward(-plg*10/2); left(90); forward(plg*10/2);right(90); pd()
for y in range(10):
  p = pos()
  for x in range(10):
    i = randint(0,1)
    if i==0:
      triangle(plg,randrange(0,360,90))
    else:
      square(plg)
    pu(); forward(plg); pd()
  pu();setpos(p);right(90);forward(plg);left(90);pd()

done()
```

Comment: Are you just trying to draw a square ?

Comment: I want to draw square exactly like this, with turtle positioned in the middle before and after drawing.

Answer (score 1):

Few observations:

> 1) Remove 'right()' from the 5th line assures a regular square
>
> 2) Adding 'time.sleep(1)' just before 'for _ in range(4):' doesn't help in any way, so we can discard a timing problem
>
> 3) 'print heading()' after every 'rt()' prints the correct values, we can also discard problems of angulation
>
> 4) Drag the window very quickly around the screen changes the appearance of the square, this is definitely a graphical error
>
> 5) `s = 66.9999999999999` returns an even square, `s = 66.99999999999999` (adding 1 extra decimal) returns as the error
>
> 6) Even after compilation of the code, the square stills uneven

Turtle source: http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/pep-0384/Lib/turtle.py

I changed your code so it draws a simple angle:

```
pu();fd(s/2);rt(90.0);pd()
for x in range(2):
    rt(90.0)
    fd(s)
done()
```

This has the same issue as yours, but if I change `fd(s/2)` to `fd(s)` everything turns well, why?

it's just a guess (do not take it as absolute truth, I'm just intrigued and trying to figure it out) but I think that it depends by your screen resolution, `odd_number%2` always returns 1, and the lines are misaligned by 1 pixel, If the value increases from 67 to 67.1 the screen reads it correctly and divides equally the space. (Mine is 1600x900)

if someone has more plausible explanations write them! This issue is interesting!

Comment: Hmmm... For one square it works. But when I draw few in a row this method sitll produces bad result. Change last line to the followin: `pu();fd(-s/2.0);rt(-90.0);fd(-s/2.0);fd(s);pd()` and add `for _ in range(3):` before first positioning (+indentations)

Comment: Thanks! I've just discovered that adding `1e-10` to `s` solves problem.

Comment: Good, edit your question so people with the same problem will know how to fix it!

Comment: Done. But If you come with other and general solution, pls let me know. Adding 1e-10 is a dirty hack.

Comment: Ok, I'll check, stay turned

Comment: Unfortunately when drawing more comlipcated stack of triangles/squares `1e-10` method doesn't work...

Comment: I'll provide one tomorrow

Comment: Provided in original question

Comment: I think I got it, it is certainly a issue related to the pixels, imagine the area of a triangle, the code TRYS to draw it as realistically as possible, but with the impediment of a predefined number of pixels where it must fits it. In the cases examined it is unable to construct an uniform triangle with the area inserted (it fails because pixels aren't infinitely small), with the result that it deforms the lines just to keep the correct value of the area.

Comment: Same with the square, half pixel is cut off so it has to deform the line in order to maintain the correct area, adding a very small value covers that extra half pixel and the line is drawn correctly

Answer (score 0):

Using python 3.5 on Mac with Yosemite 10.10.5, it draws a perfect square.[image]

You might print the turtle coordinates after every drawing instruction to figure out what's going on on your platform.